# Splitting a line into words in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to split a line into words. I know this can be done with this

```
For word in $line; do echo $word; done
```

But I want to make group of 3-3 words. So my question is, how can I split a line in group of 3-3 words ?

For example

```
Input : I am writing this line for testing the code.  

Output :  
I am writing
this line for
testing the code.
```

Comment: Will it always be 9 words per line?  Or do you mean divide an n-word line as evenly as possible into three groups?

Comment: No there may be more than 9 words. I just wanted to split the whole line into group of 3 words. In case total no of words is not multiple of 3, Last line may have less than three words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start you can use this, which reads every word into an array

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
while read
do
    for word in $REPLY
    do
        A[$total]=$word
        total=$(($total+1))
    done
done < input.txt

for i in "${A[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Next step is to use `seq` or similar to loop through the array and print it in groups of three.

Comment: Glad I'd could help. Welcome to SO, don't forget to upvote if you liked the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Read the words three at a time. Set the line being read from to the remainder:

```
while read -r remainder
do
    while [[ -n $remainder ]]
    do
        read -r a b c remainder <<< "$remainder"
        echo "$a $b $c"
    done
done < inputfile
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have suggested as well, just better written.

Answer (score 3):

What about paste command

```
for word in $line; do echo $word; done | paste - - -
for word in $line; do echo $word; done | paste -d" " - - -
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy regex exercise.

```
sed -e "s/\([^\ ]*\ [^\ ]*\ [^\ ]*\)\ /\1\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/g"
```

The only tricky part was getting the new line in the sed, as there isn't a standard for that.

```
$ echo "I am writing this line for testing the code."|sed -e "s/\([^\ ]*\ [^\ ]*\ [^\ ]*\)\ /\1\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/g"
I am writing
this line for
testing the code.
```

You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `set` to set your input as positional arguments, and process them in groups of three. That way you don't need anything fancy or bash-specific:

```
line="I am writing this line for testing the code."

set junk $line
shift
while [ $# -ge 3 ]; do
  echo "Three words: $1 $2 $3"
  shift 3
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a non-generic straight forward solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
path_to_file=$1
while read line
do
counter=1;
    for word in $line
    do
        echo -n $word" ";
    if (($counter % 3 == 0))
      then
        echo "";
    fi
    let counter=counter+1;
    done
done < ${path_to_file}
```

Save that in a script, give it a name (test.sh for example) and set it to execution mode. Than if your text is saved in "myfile.txt" call it like this:

```
test.sh myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of possible solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

line="I am writing this line for testing the code."


i=0
for word in $line; do
    ((++i))
    if [[ $i -eq 3 ]]; then
        i=0
        echo "$word"
    else
        echo -ne "$word "
    fi
done
```